# Why should I disable https while creating new ASP.NET project?

Tags: asp.net, .net

I am new to ASP.NET and following  the basic tutorial on building simple web app. While creating the new web app through this command

```
dotnet new webapp -o myApp --no-https
```

Why do people generally prefer to disable HTTPS?

Comment: In local development, it is safe to disable https. Secondly setting up local keys for ssl to enable https is additional step. So to make development simple and easy, disabling https is fine.

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial samples made for learning and they are not real product.
therefore the one's that prepare those tutorial doesn't want to educate how SSL and certificates works.

Furthermore that the local https certificates are self sign and not a real certificates.

**The use of SSL only complicates the education process so its not relevant**